# 404 Cannot find "/dist/vue-router.js" in vue-router@4.0.15

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have several script tag vue.js projects, all using CDN scripts, and all working fine until recently now all of a sudden all are getting a 404 error for https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4.0.15/dist/vue-router.js, so I figured I could just find a copy of that script and replace but seems this is not the way as I have tried replacing it with several of the same from other CDNs with no joy, any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Here is a codepen with the issue https://codepen.io/flashvenom/pen/RwZxddQ

Hit settings > JS, to access the script tags

Cheers

```
  template: '<div><div class="content single row"></div>'
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project is using Vue 2, and the `latest` tags of `vue`, `vuex`, and `vue-router` were all [updated to be specific to Vue 3](https://twitter.com/vuejs/status/1490592213184573441).

Your Codepen's JS settings has these two external script URLs that default to the `latest` tags:

```bash
# vue-router@latest = 4.0.15 (not compatible with Vue 2, but CDN link is also broken apparently)
https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js

# vuex@latest = 4.0.2 (not compatible with Vue 2)
https://unpkg.com/vuex
```

#### Solution

Update those URLs to use versions that are compatible with Vue 2 (i.e., the 3.x versions of those libs in this case):

```bash
https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3
https://unpkg.com/vuex@3
```

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/LYQQjqV?editors=1010)